# What should follow "cause" (the verb)?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I wrote the following sentence, but I am not sure it is correct.

> All the moderators asking for blacklisting a tag would not probably cause the tag being blacklisted.

Is it correct to use *the tag being blacklisted* after *cause*? In Italian, where I could not use a noun as a verb<sup>*****</sup>, I would probably say *causerebbe l'aggiunta del tag alla lista dei tag bloccati* (which is roughly equivalent to *would cause the addition of the tag to the list of the blocked tags*). The equivalent phrase in English seems too long, even when I replace *to the list of the blocked tags* with *to the blacklist*.

What is a more correct way of rephrasing that sentence?

<sup>*****</sup> What I mean is that, for example, the Italian translation of *list* as noun is *lista* (or *elenco*); in English *list* is also the bare infinite of a verb, but in Italian the infinite of the verb would be *elencare* (not *listare*), since the infinite always ends in *-are*, *-ere*, or *-ire*.

Comment: *Not probably* is grammatical, but *probably not* is the unmarked form, appearing over 100 times more often in COCA.  Here, *would not probably* is grammatical but unnatural.

Comment: @snailboat It occurs to me that this is useful for emphasis in a construction like: No, he {wouldn't | would not} **probably** do it, he would **certainly** do it. The binding of the "not" is different and doesn't refer to the probability of the inaction, but rather criticizes the other speaker's assessment of probability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this construction, *cause* takes three complements:

1. subject
2. object
3. *to*-infinitival clause

Compare the following examples:

> He caused it to rain.　 　 　( He<sub>1</sub> caused<sub>verb</sub> it<sub>2</sub> [ to rain ]<sub>3</sub>. )
>
> *He caused it raining.　　　( He<sub>1</sub> caused<sub>verb</sub> it<sub>2</sub> *raining<sub>3</sub>. )

The former is fine, but the latter is ungrammatical.  The third complement must be a *to*-infinitival clause, not a gerund.

---

In your example, *the tag* is fine.  But *being blacklisted* is a gerund, so it doesn't work as the third complement.

Here's one way to rephrase your sentence:

> Even if all the moderators asked for a tag to be blacklisted, it would probably not cause it to be blacklisted.

Here, I think the repetition of *to be blacklisted* is slightly unnatural, but I left it in because it's part of the construction we're discussing.  I think I would personally phrase it like this:

> Even if all the moderators asked for a tag to be blacklisted, it probably wouldn't happen.

Comment: Kaz's answer seems fine to me, but I decided to finish my own and post it anyway.

Comment: This is good, and it's significant that we agree that "Even" is called for in the improved sentence.

Answer (score 4):

- cause + *to verb*:

  "Even all the moderators asking {for *the blacklisting of* a tag | *for* a tag *to be blacklisted* } would probably not cause {the tag | it} *to be* blacklisted" [Note both corrections.]

  "Bad engineering caused the bridge *to collapse*."
- cause + *noun phrase*:

  "Smoking causes cancer."

  "Low octane fuel causes knocking."